# Completar un datetimepicker con los datos de otro

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

Tengo 2 datepicker:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
.

En el primero se muestra una fecha en que se ingreso un registro
En el segundo se muestra la fecha de edicion
¿Cómo puedo hacer que el segundo datepicker muestre el mismo valor que el primero por defecto y que tambien al cambiar los datos del primer datepicker el segundo cambie?

Este es mi script

```
<script>
$('.fecha').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tiempo').mdtimepicker();
});
```

Comment: let old = $('.fecha').val();  $('new_date').val(old)

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cOutDate').datepicker("setDate", $('#cInDate').val());
});
```